# The correct name for those who work in IT

Tags: word-meaning

We name the person who works in development "*A developer*".
What is the equivalent for a person who works in Network, Security or IT domains?

Usually I use Network guy, Security guy, or IT guy..., but I don't think it is the correct word.

Comment: *Tech support*?

Comment: @Chenmunka The OP seems to want a term that *doesn't* refer to a *developer*, though. In that context (and in non-technical conversation), 'working in IT' is often shorthand for "someone who gets / keeps computers working". Hence my suggestion.

Comment: @Chenmunka No offense intended, by the way. I studied Computer Science at university; I understand the point you're making.

Comment: Thank you @Lawrence usually we use `A developer` for the person who works in development so what should we name that person who work in network or security so i need two names not a generale name?

Comment: @YCF_L Your question is too broad. There are many roles within those fields. Director, manager, software architect, technician and probably others might all fit. Which part of IT operations are you referring to? (Your "__ guy" label tends to suggest *technician*.)

Comment: @Lawrence i already mention this in my question i want Network and Security domain

Comment: @YCF_L Yes, I understand. But the directors of a company specialising in routers could say they're working in the Network domain. A manager in a company specialising in anti-virus software can say they're working in the Security domain. And so on. You need to be more specific as to which part of the *operations* (of Network / Security) you're referring to. The person who calls the shots for the whole company? The one who comes over to fix things? Someone who answers calls? Or ...?

Comment: i need it in general @Lawrence a general name

Comment: @Chenmunka You seem to be more in tune with this OP. Can you help?

Comment: As I understand from your question and comments, you want a term that can cover, say, an accountant working at Google (an IT company). *Technologist*, or even *IT specialist*, doesn't really fit. Neither does *IT guy*, for that matter (they might not have a clue about IT; their work relates to the finances of the company). Perhaps you could try saying "someone who works in the IT industry". Sorry I can't be of more help at this time.

Comment: Actually, IT guy etc.  are commonly used.  Different companies tend to use different, largely invented, job titles.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is asking about employment titles, which are decided at the convenience of an employer, and is not about learning English.

Comment: @user3169 where should i ask this question then ?

Comment: As @Chenmunka said, "companies tend to use different, largely invented, job titles", so there really isn't a correct answer, rather choices like "IT technician/engineer/specialist/guy/etc." The real problem with your question is that you are trying to compare a noun (developer) with "Network/Security/IT" which in your context is a noun modifier. I suppose you could have an "IT Developer", right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct term is "**[IT engineer](http://techacute.com/what-does-an-it-engineer-do/)**" and they can be separated into groups "**[information security engineer](http://www.jobhero.com/information-security-engineer-job-description/#)**", "**[computer hardware engineer](https://www.bls.gov/ooh/architecture-and-engineering/computer-hardware-engineers.htm#tab-2)**", "**[network engineer](http://searchsdn.techtarget.com/definition/network-engineer)**", "**[software engineer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_engineer)**", "[**information systems security engineer (ISSE)**](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/I/information_systems_security_engineer.html)" and many more.

You might also call him an [**IT person**](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091027042409AAgq7Yi).